# populate field from parent schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a transactions Schema as follows:

```
  const transactionSchema = mongoose.Schema(  {
       amount: Number,
       order: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
          ref: 'Order'
        }
      },
      {
        toJson: { virtuals: true },
        toObject: { virtuals: true }
      }
    );
```

and an Order Schema that has a driver field as follows (each transaction is related to one Order)

```
const orderSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    title: String,
     driver: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
    })
```

I need to pull the driver name from the user schema when i query (find) a transaction
My user Schema is as follows:

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: String, })

How is that possibel? I tried virtuals as follows but it didnt work

```
transactionSchema.virtual('driverName', {
  ref: 'User',
  foreignField: 'name', //name of reference field in Review model
  localField: 'driver' //name of reference in local Model
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this can be solved with deep populate (Populating across multiple levels)
as per mongoose [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#deep-populate)